# What is the recommended way to copy a .NET exe and its DLLs with a NuGet package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I am creating a NuGet package, which is a library DLL. I did this successfully.

However I would like to have a .NET exe (and its dependent assemblies) also in the target machine. It is completely OK if the .exe and these dlls are under the solution's package folder.

If it is possible I do not want to create a standard Windows installer and run it silently.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to edit your .nuspec file.  You can include a  element to include additional files in your package.  Look at what else you can do by looking at the [specs](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference).

You can run your exe by creating a powershell script during package installation.

Comment: As I stated in my original question this is a _usual_ library DLL, the most typical and intended usage of NuGet. The additional .NET exe and its .DLLs are intended to use with this DLL, in development cycle when running tests. Also please note the _copy_ word in the question title. 
I was not asking about how to use NuGet as "generic application installler"

Comment: @g.pickardou then you should probably edit your question, because its very unclear as it is now.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from NuGet 2.0 a package can contain a "tools" folder. Here you can put exe, scripts and so on. 
http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Framework_Version_Folder_Structure

Binary under this folder will not be referenced, just copied on the machine.

Hope it helps.